# Python: p value from scipy is not correct

Tags: python, pandas

i want to calculate a p value with the package scipy. this is the code is used:

```
x = st.ttest_1samp(df_efw.stack(),np.round(np.mean(df_lw).mean(),2))
```

This is my output:

```
Ttest_1sampResult(statistic=-1.3939917717040629, pvalue=0.16382682901590806)
```

I also calculated it manually and my statistic value is correct but the p value is not..? The p value can be read on the standard normal distribution table.
So the problem is: if you read the table you will see that -1,39399 has a p value of 0,0823 and not 0,1638. So i am thinking that i did the code wrong or i am interpreting something wrong. What is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `ttest_1samp` returns the two-sided or two-tailed p-value, which is twice the single-sided p-value due to the symmetry about 0 of the t distribution. Consistent with this, your manually computed single-sided p-value is (roughly) half of SciPy's p-value.

One solution is just to divide the two-sided p-value from `ttest_1samp` by 2. In SciPy 1.6.0 and later, you can pass the argument `alternative='greater'` or `alternative='less'` to get a single-sided p-value.

##### Further Reading

`ttest_1samp` documentation: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ttest_1samp.html

The GitHub issue where the `alternative` argument was proposed: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/12597

The resulting pull request: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/12597